# Не могу спарсить steam

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Было расширение для хрома, там парсил эту страницу без ошибок. Сейчас же ошибка `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198380691270/games/?tab=all'.` Вот код:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198380691270/games/?tab=all', false);
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {
    console.error( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
} else {
    var rgGames;
    eval($(xhr.responseText).find('script:last').html().split('var')[1]);
    $.each(rgGames, function(ind, val) {
        if(havegames[val.name]){
            havegames[val.name]++;
        } else{
            havegames[val.name] = 1;
        }
    });
};
```

Пробовал на PHP, там просто без ошибки ничего не выдает.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в том, что Steam отвечает не всем, а только тем пользователям у которых указан  **HTTP** заголовок `User-Agent`, просто из браузера обратитесь к этому адресу, сохраните все заголовки которые отправил браузер серверу, а потом продублируйте их в запросе с вашего программного приложения.

Comment: Судя по вкладке `Network` в chrome, `User-Agent` отправляется идентично тому что было в расширении, да и тем более `Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"`. Я нашел различие в запросах и это `Query String Parameters`: где удалось `tab=all`, а где не удалось `tab: all`, ну еще Referer отличается и Origin появился (но это потому что не на главную страницу захожу).

Comment: Попробуйте сделать абсолютного идентичный запрос, и преобразовать строку запроса в URL подобную.

Comment: Все сделал как на рабочем варианте, ответ такой же приходит, но обрабатывать его не хочет никак, все та же ошибка. Единственное не могу задать `cookie` из-за ошибки `Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"`, хотя в `Network` имеются куки. Даже порты открыл, сайт запустил, в Steam API зарегистрировал сайт и ничего не меняется. Скрины вкладки `Network` https://imgur.com/a/RcJKLzF